# How to create a valid docx with a table using Open XML

Tags: c#, .net, docx, openxml-sdk

So far every example I was able to find here or elsewhere (like https://stackoverflow.com/a/72016283/13831836) was a barebones code that creates something that may or may not be opened by MS Word, knowing Microsoft's attitude towards enforcing standards, but is not a valid document. And by valid I mean:

- Libre Office opens it and displays more or less correctly (a must)
- Open Office opens it and displays more or less correctly (a must)
- MS Open XML Productivity Tool validates it (nice to have)

document in question is rather simple, a short paragraph followed by a large table (600+ rows) followed by another short paragraph.

I attempted to fix errors displayed by Productivity Toolkit on my own, alas it turned out to be too difficult without knowing much more about the SDK and the format than I do. Most of the errors have to do with invalid children of a table, a row, etc., or missing Styles and so on, some of them I could fix with the help of internet search, but not all.

I am not against using libraries built on top of The Open XML SDK provided the license is right, but again I wasn't able to find one that actually works yet.

Comment: I don’t really understand what you actually want from us? A sample of a table?  if so why would it be better than the one you mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/a/72016283/13831836 ?!? so currently I am like „cool story, so what?“

Comment: @RandRandom I want to know the answer to the question "How to create a valid docx with a table using Open XML?" a sample of a code that does produce that would be one of the possible answers. A link to an article / guide teaching that would be another. I am sure there can be more possible answers. I hope that clarifies.

Comment: Microsoft Word is not OpenXml, but can read XML.  I would first manually open Microsoft Word and using the File Open menu with Open XML option.  See the results.  Programming will only get you the same results as manually reading the file.  If you are satisfied with the manual results I would use the Microsoft Word Interop Library and do the same you did manually.

Comment: @jdweng my question was about Open XML, not MS Word or Interop, but thanks for suggestion.

Comment: You said "Open Office opens it and displays more or less correctly (a must)".  Most people think MS Office is OpenXML and it isn't.

Comment: I gave up and instead of trying to create a document from scratch, I create it from a docx file saved with libre office, that solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to support Libre Office, Open Office, and Word, then

1. Use each of them to create the document in the format that you desire.
2. Open each of the documents with the other two programs (for example, if you created a document in Word, ensure that it successfully opens with Libre Office and Open Office).
3. Once you've identified which document works with all three, then use the Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool to generate the code needed to programmatically create the document.

---

**Given**: One has identified that a document we created with *LibreOffice* also works correctly in *OpenOffice* and *Word*.

One may consider using the document created in *LibreOffice* as a template, and  modify it using NuGet package [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml).

If desired, one can create the entire document programmatically. One may start by reading [Welcome to the Open XML SDK for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk), as well, as the articles it references. However, there is an easier way. One can download and install the [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5) which one can use to generate the code. Then, one can then modify the code to suit one's needs. One must understand that the *Open XML SDK Productivity Tool* hasn't been updated in a while and may not support the latest versions of *OpenXML* (ie: the latest version of *DocumentFormat.OpenXml, LibreOffice, MS Office, etc...*). The versions I used for testing, are mentioned throughout the post.

---

**Pre-requisite**:

- Ensure that you have installed the [.NET 8 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0).

**Create a new Windows Forms App** (name: OpenXmlLibreOfficeTest)

**Note**: For *Framework*, ensure you select *.NET 8*.

**Open Solution Explorer**

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**

**Download/install NuGet package**: DocumentFormat.OpenXml (v. 2.19.0)

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name>
- Select **Manage NuGet Packages...**
- Click **Browse** tab
- In search box, type **DocumentFormat.OpenXml**
- Select desired version (ex: 2.19.0)
- Click **Install**

**Add a class to the project** (name: HelperOpenXml.cs)

**HelperOpenXml.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OpenXmlLibreOfficeTest
{
    public class HelperOpenXml
    {
    }
}
```

In the OP, you stated that you have a document that has a paragraph, then a table, then another paragraph. I created a document using [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) (v.7.5.9) for testing (name: Test.docx) which looks like:

[image]

Open the .docx file using the *Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool* (ex: Test.docx).

[image]

Click **Reflect Code**

[image]

Copy all of the code shown in the *Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool* to our class (ex: HelperOpenXml.cs) and then rename the *namespace*,
*GeneratedCode*, to *OpenXmlLibreOfficeTest* and class *GeneratedClass* to *HelperOpenXml*.

Alternatively, one can first copy the using directives shown in *Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool*, and then copy the code within the class (*GeneratedClass*) to our class (ex: HelperOpenXml.cs) - this will eliminate the need to rename the *namespace* and *class*.

**Build your application**

- In VS menu, select **Build**
- Select **Build <project name>**

You may see errors such as the following:

[image]

If so, add the following using directives to your class (ex: HelperOpenXml.cs):

```
using Color = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Color;
using Font = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Font;
using FontFamily = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.FontFamily;
```

Then, **Build your application**

- In VS menu, select **Build**
- Select **Build <project name>**

---

To create the *.docx* file programmatically, just call `CreatePackage`.

**Usage**:

**Note**: I've added a button (name: buttonCreateDocument) to the form and double-clicked it to create the event handler.

```
private void buttonCreateDocument_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog())
    {
        sfd.Filter = "OpenXml Document|*.docx";

        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            HelperOpenXml helperOpenXml = new HelperOpenXml();
            helperOpenXml.CreatePackage(sfd.FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Now, one can modify the code within the class (ex: HelperOpenXml.cs) as desired. For example, you'll notice that all of the table data is, in essence, hard-coded. This code can be re-written.

Perhaps one has data stored in a [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-8.0) or maybe one has a class

**Computer**

```
public class Computer
{
    public string? Make { get; set; }
    public string? Model { get; set; }
    public string? SerialNumber { get; set; }
}
```

and defines `List<Computer> computers = new List<Computer>();` (see [List<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-8.0)) As you probably already know, one would modify the code to create the table rows within a loop.