# Add Image to Libre Office Writer with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, image, visual-studio-2022, libreoffice, writer

For days, I've tried to add an image to programmatically created Libre Office (v7.4) Writer Document using VB.net (using Visual Studio 2022) with no success.  The LibreOffice SDK I'm using was downloaded using NuGet. None of the instructions or examples I've found work for me.  Can anyone share a listing on how to do this, specifically to insert a JPG into a cell in a table and dock it there, or alternately size it and center it in the cell.

I have studied the Libre Office site, the Open Office site and other good instructional sites/documents including Andrew D. Pitonyak's "Open Office Macros Explained."  Of course I've also Googled everywhere to find instructions and/or examples, and have found many, but none are specifically use VB.Net.  I'm familiar, but not fluent in the other languages in which the examples have been provided, so I've used several different conversion tools to generate VB.Net code. I've had good success using these tools in numerous other efforts, but not here.

The best source has been Libre Office's own (very good) "WriterDemo," written specifically in VB.Net.  This demo worked straight away for me and I've attempted to build on it and its methodologies for building components, objects and interfaces for writing text, building and filling tables, building and filling text frames etc.  But even this hasn't gotten me to the promised land (embedding jpg images).  Finally, since I've tried so many variations on the use of Graphics Objects to do this, providing a listing of what is not working would likely lead to 'go-backs' about whatever non-working code I might provide.  Instead I'll simply ask (and hope) for a working listing.  Help!

Comment: There are several [C# to VB converters](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+to+VB+converters) that may help you to understand C# examples.

Comment: Here's a nice [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77816338/10024425) that describes a process that you may find useful. The _promised land_ awaits. The question that remains is: Are you willing to put forth the effort to walk through the gate?

Comment: Thanks user246821.  At one point in my searching, I read someone comment that the Libre/Open Office documents were all "compressed XML" and that the best way was to ignore the LO/OO SDKs and uncompress/open an ODT as an XML file then  recompress back to an ODT file.  I assume that is what your second comment suggests...or am I leaping to a desired conclusion.  BTW I looked at that for a time and (perhaps woefully) discounted it to stay focused on an SDK solutions.  Please elaborate.

Comment: Must have been another post you read. The post I referenced is about first creating the desired document in _Word, Libre Office, or Open Office_. Then use the _Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool_ to view the structure and also use it to generate the code. The code will be in C#, but you can use an online converter to convert it.

Comment: Roger that and thanks again... Work involved here... I'll be heads down for a while.  "Film at Eleven"

Comment: Thanks again user246821!  I believe I have applied your suggestion, but before I self generate an answer and (try to) give you credit , please confirm that the following is what you were leading me to see/do.

1) Generate a template in (either MS Word or) Libre Office Writer which includes all of my desired features (i.e., an image in a table cell)
2) Save the file as an MS Word Document
3) Read the file into the XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool and generate C# code
4) Convert the C# into VB.Net
5) Copy the VB.Net code into a Visual Studio, VB.Net Class File

Comment: I did all this, ran the converted VB.Net code and it successfully created an MS Word Doc (I used MS Word 2007 for all).  I then opened the MS Word Doc with Libre Office and lo and behold it was identical to the file I loaded into the the XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool! Happy Day!!!

Comment: It does work and for sure I believe is extensible for my needs.  Unfortunately instead of the < 2 hundred lines of code that I was working with the generated code is almost 30,000!!  Most of it seems to be in the generation of the 3 (empty!) tables that are in the template file.
I am undaunted however.  If it works and there's no other easier way to do this I can live with it!
Thanks!!

Comment: _Save the file as an MS Word Document_: My comment was: _Word, Libre Office, or Open Office_. You may consider creating a file in _Libre Office_ to see if the code generated is less than that of the one created by Word.

Comment: I created a Word document containing a table with two columns (_Username_ and _ProfileImage_). I added two rows of data to the table. The code generated by _Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool_ is  2,234 lines. However, I notice that there is quite a bit of styling code for styles that I haven't used. While, Word may include these by default, one may be able to remove any unused styling/theme code which will shorten the amount of code.

Comment: @PeteBrown: To give me _credit_, you can upvote my post that I referred you to and also add a reference to it in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A strong thumbs up to user246821.  But I cannot declare this as a fully answered question....

I was able to use the Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool to generate (a lot) of VB.Net code in conjunction with a LibreOffice Writer Document.  Unfortunately the tool only allows you to decompose an MS Word Document. So the process I had to use was the following:

1. create a Writer Document
2. use Writer to convert it to an MS Word (2007) document
3. use the productivity tool to generate C# code
4. convert the C# code to VB.Net using the online Telrik code converter
5. run the VB.Net code (successfully btw) to generate the identical MS Word document
6. use LibreOffice Writer to Open that MS Word Document and convert it to a LibreOffice format document

It is definitely a circular path to do this and it didn't avoid using MS Word as I desired.  But worse, modifying the Writer Document to MS Word did not preserve the table names I'd assigned to each of the tables.  So my hopes of easily manipulating the VB.Net code (actually finding references to individual tables) was derailed.  This of course too was not insurmountable, but with things stacking up against use this as an easy solution I gave up on this approach.

But if the VB.Net code had a small number of LOC, I might have continued on this path, but as I said, this created a ton of code for a relatively small document.  I ended up with almost 30K LOC for a document that contained a total of 4 empty tables.  While much of the code was generated to specify 'style' properties, it was difficult to wade through.  But overall this did not bode well for using this methodology to generate code to either generate LibreOffice Documents from scratch or even call up and modify templates of files.

All that said, the XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool is very impressive and something to consider if you want to build or modify MS Word Documents.  Take Note: it is still available but MS declares it to be deprecated.

But I'm still looking for code to add and image to a Libre Office Writer Document using VB.Net.  Anyone?

Comment: Have you tried renaming the _.odt_ file with a _.zip_ extension, and then unzipping the file? This will allow you to view the _.XML_ files, which form the _.odt_ file which may be helpful in your endeavor.

Comment: Yes that's how I had to do it.  And... I only have LibreOffice Writer, I do not have MS Word.  I detest paying a subscription for a product that I formerly bought and paid for just once & used for years.  LibreOffice (the entire suite) is a free download and is much more than sufficiently featured for my use, and it is compatible with MS Word.  I recommend it to everyone.  
So unfortunately, I cannot compare the output from the XML 2.5 Productivity Tool of a LO Document converted to MSWord Format from the output of a document created straight from MSWord.  But I suspect it would be the same.

Comment: To answer your last comment more specifically, neither the .odt file nor the .odt file converted to MS word would unzip after changing the extension to '.zip.'  I'm guessing that this is because MS Word document file format before 2011 were not in a zipped XML format.  So the compatibility I mentioned is the result of MS and Libre Office both accepting files in backwards file formats (that are not in file formats that are part of their current configurations).

Comment: Not sure whether or not it is a typo, but the extension to rename to is `.zip` not `.zip.` I've tested unzipping `test.odt` to `test.zip` and then right-clicking the file and unzipping it and it does work. Afterwards one can view the _.xml_ files it contains.

Comment: _I detest paying a subscription for a product that I formerly bought and paid for just once & used for years_: Not to worry it's now a yearly subscription, so you don't buy it once and use it forever. You pay for a subscription every year. Once your subscription expires, you no longer get to use it.

Comment: Your statement has a tone that makes it seem as if you don't value other peoples' time.

Comment: Not a typo, just the end of the sentence.

Comment: And I apologize if the tone sounded unappreciative of other folks' time.  The comment is aligned with the exact opposite view. I'll explain, but I first want to emphasize my gratitude for folks such as yourself taking the time to respond to my queries because you do it for only good and helpful reasons and that for me is the height of reasons for anyone to do anything.
But my negative tone is the result of companies making tons of money on subscriptions for the use of their software whether the user uses that software once or 10000 times each year.

Comment: Consider folks who buy a new computer and are (virtually) forced to buy software tools to allow them to create or open various document types because they know they'll need that capability at some point even if only once a year.  The money that they spend is also equivalent to their time; e.g., their time earning the money to spend on the right to use such software just a minimal number of times.

Comment: One solution to this is one that such companies would never apply because they would make far less money.  This would be to collect a minimal per usage charge that had a cap at some level.

Comment: So my comment was to (lamely I confess) suggest that public domain software that only seeks donations from users, such as LibreOffice is a better way to go.  Sadly, folks who download 'free' software do not often/always make donations to such software developers, so relying on that approach suffers from that issue. 
If such solutions are not entirely viable or desirable, I only hope there are other ideas to solve this dilemma that are equally as fair to consumers as well as software developers.