# Facing error while opening excel after using OpenXML

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

We are using OpenXML to generate Excel files, and tried with this code, but we're getting an error while trying to open the Excel file:

> There is problem with some content in 'test.xslx'. Please let us know if you want to recover.

Code:

```
public byte[] ExportDatatoExcel()
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheet.AddWorkbookPart();

    workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
    Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

    // OpenSheet
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();
    var sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "test" };
    sheets.Append(sheet);

    OpenXmlWriter DataWriter = OpenXmlWriter.Create(worksheetPart);

    // getting error because of writing to worksheet
    DataWriter.WriteStartElement(worksheetPart.Worksheet);
 
    DataWriter.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());
    DataWriter.WriteEndElement();

    DataWriter.Close();

    worksheetPart = null;
    workbookPart.Workbook.Save();

    spreadsheet.Save();
    spreadsheet.Close();

    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

I am getting an issue while trying to open the downloaded file. When I tried to change this line

```
DataWriter.WriteStartElement(worksheetPart.Worksheet);
```

to

```
DataWriter.WriteStartElement(new Worksheet());
```

it's working fine, but when I try to check `worksheetpart` instance, it's showing `Worksheet` property as "System.IO exception".

Please suggest what the issue might be

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77816338/10024425 . The post was written for _.docx_, but the same process will work for _.xlsx_.

Comment: @user246821 the link shared is of not much useful. please share if there is any other link available for excel

Comment: The link is useful if you follow the steps. Use Excel to create the file as desired, Then, use the _Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool_ to generate the C# code which you can refactor.

Comment: Can you share the method `DataWriter.WriteStartElement(worksheetPart.Worksheet);`?

Comment: DataWriter.WriteStartElement(worksheetPart.Worksheet) is abstract method in OpenXMLWriter class.Its not something we implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.
If we change the line with worksheet,

```
worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();
to worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
```