C# Openxml WordProccesing
I am working on a project and i wan to generate a report to values that a bot complicated so i need to make 2 rows inside one cell can u help me with it
this is my code of making a a table but i want to make it do it without ruining the other rows
on cell 25 i want to make that it takes 2 rows inside that cell to show to values as well as 26, 27, 28 and 29
this is my code
private void AddObjTable(WordprocessingDocument doc, ObjectivesDTO data)
{
// Get the main document part
MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;

// Get the body of the document
Body body = mainPart.Document.Body;

// Create a new table
Table table1 = new Table();

// Set table width to 50% (optional, adjust as needed)
table1.AppendChild(new TableProperties(
     new TableWidth() { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa, Width = "100%" },
        new TableBorders(
            new TopBorder() { Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Single), Size = 1 },
            new BottomBorder() { Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Single), Size = 1 },
            new LeftBorder() { Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Single), Size = 1 },
            new RightBorder() { Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Single), Size = 1 },
            new InsideHorizontalBorder() { Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Single), Size = 1 },
            new InsideVerticalBorder() { Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Single), Size = 1 }
        )
    ));

TableRow headerRow = new TableRow();
TableCell cell11 = CreateTableCellWithTextAndProperties("", 2, "e4d2ae");
TableCell cell12 = CreateTableCellWithTextAndProperties("", 20, "e4d2ae");
TableCell cell13 = CreateTableCellWithTextAndProperties("", 35, "e4d2ae");
TableCell cell14 = CreateTableCellWithTextAndProperties("", 14, "e4d2ae");
TableCell cell15 = CreateTableCellWithTextAndProperties("", 6, "9a7732");
TableCell cell16 = CreateTableCellWithTextAndProperties("", 6, "9a7732");
TableCell cell17 = CreateTableCellWithTextAndProperties("", 6, "9a7732");
TableCell cell18 = CreateTableCellWithTextAndProperties("", 6, "9a7732");
TableCell cell19 = CreateTableCellWithTextAndProperties("", 6, "9a7732");
headerRow.Append(cell19, cell18, cell17, cell16, cell15, cell14, cell13, cell12, cell11);
table1.Append(headerRow);

foreach (var obj in data.kPIMainDTOs)
{       
    
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell21 = CreateTableCellWithTextAndProperties("", 2, "ffffff");
        TableCell cell22 = CreateTableCellWithTextAndProperties("", 20, "ffffff");
        TableCell cell23 = CreateTableCellWithTextAndProperties("", 35, "ffffff");
        TableCell cell24 = CreateTableCellWithTextAndProperties("", 14, "ffffff");

        TableCell cell25 = CreateTableCellWithTextAndProperties("", 6, "ffffff");
        
        TableCell cell26 = CreateTableCellWithTextAndProperties("", 6, "ffffff");
        
        TableCell cell27 = CreateTableCellWithTextAndProperties("", 6, "ffffff");
        
        TableCell cell28 = CreateTableCellWithTextAndProperties("", 6, "ffffff");
        
        TableCell cell29 = CreateTableCellWithTextAndProperties("", 6, "ffffff");
        
        row.Append(cell29, cell28, cell27, cell26, cell25, cell24, cell23, cell22, cell21);
        table1.Append(row);
    
}



foreach (var paragraph in doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Paragraph>())
{
    var text = paragraph.InnerText;
    if (text.Contains("@Table"))
    {
        // Clear the paragraph content
        paragraph.RemoveAllChildren();

        // Create paragraph properties for center alignment
        ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties = new ParagraphProperties(
            new Justification() { Val = JustificationValues.Center }
        );

        // Apply the paragraph properties to the paragraph
        paragraph.Append(paragraphProperties);

        // Insert the table before the paragraph
        paragraph.Parent.InsertBefore(table1, paragraph);

        // Remove the paragraph containing the search text
        paragraph.Remove();
    }
}

}

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77816338/10024425
