How to Insert an Image into Specific Line, Column, Page Number in Microsoft Word Using C#
I'm developing a C# application that automates the process of inserting images into Microsoft Word documents. A key feature I'm implementing requires me to locate a specific piece of text ("Signature Name") within the document and then insert an image immediately above this text. Additionally, I need to ensure that the image is placed on the correct page, which might involve navigating through multiple pages if the text isn't found on the current page.
Here's what I've attempted so far:

Opening and Manipulating Documents: I can successfully open existing Word documents and perform basic operations like inserting text or images at the cursor's location.
Locating Text: I've managed to write a function that searches for the text Signature Name within the document. However, I'm unsure how to proceed once I've located the text to insert the image precisely above it.
Inserting Images at Specific Locations: My attempts to insert images at specific lines and columns have been unsuccessful. I've explored the Range object and its properties but haven't found a straightforward way to use them for this purpose.
Given these challenges, I'm looking for guidance on how to:

After locating the text Signature Name, calculate the line number above it where the image should be inserted.
Determine the appropriate column and page number for the insertion, ensuring the image aligns correctly with the document's layout.
Insert the image at the calculated position, taking into account the document's pagination and the precise location within a page.
Any insights, examples, or resources that could help me achieve this functionality would be greatly appreciated. I'm particularly interested in methods or properties of the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word library that facilitate precise positioning of elements within a Word document.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77816338/10024425
