MS Office Interop Word: How to merge multiple documents and have them include the original footer?
I'm a beginner trying to code a program that would merge all the Word documents in a single directory and combine them altogether into a giant one.
The code I've so far looks like this:
foreach (string file in directory) {
   Word.Document tempDoc = app.Open(file);
   tempDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
   tempDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
   finalDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste();
}
finalDoc.SaveAs2(ref filename);
finalDoc.Close();

The code functions properly but the only thing is that it got rid of the original footer in each file, is there a way for me to keep the original footer when I'm copying and pasting the selection over? Thank you :)

You may consider using NuGet package DocumentFormat.OpenXml instead of Interop.Word. The following  may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77816338/10024425
