OfficeMath appending error in OpenXML in C#
I am trying to use WordprocessingDocument of OpenXML in C# to create MS WORD document.
I succeeded to add the normal paragraph, but, I have problem on adding math equation.
I got the idea to use OfficeMath from GPT, and I tried to add the simple text data into OfficeMath as follows,
            OfficeMath officeMath = new OfficeMath();

            Run run = new Run();
            run.Append(new Text("test text"));
            officeMath.Append(run);
            return officeMath;

Here I had an error in execution on the line "officeMath.Append(run);".
The exception shows "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Non-composite elements do not have child elements.'"
despite I add the text element to "run".
Is the any example to add math equation to the paragraph for WordprocessingDocument in C#?

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77816338/10024425

Thank you for the advice! I could access to the documents and I found the solution about my problem.
I should not add the any text elements into omath, but, just I should add officemath to Run as its child.
Following codes worked well to make OfficeMath in WORD file.
`
Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph();
OfficeMath omath = new OfficeMath();
Run run2 = new Run();
run2.Append(omath);
run2.Append(new Text("a"));
run2.Append(new Text("="));
run2.Append(new Text("b"));
run2.Append(new Text("+"));
run2.Append(new Text("C"));
paragraph2.Append(run2);
`
