Docx Validation error: The element has invalid child element http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main:rtl
I have a docx generated with Text Control, integrated into a frontend Angular app.
The file is uploaded to the backend via a rest service.
An example file can be found here: https://github.com/user-attachments/files/16088624/TextControlDoc.docx
The service validates the file using Open-XML-SDK (https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK), but returns the following error:
The element has invalid child element http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main:rtl
Below is the code:
Stream fileStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(documento.StringBase64));
string errorDescription = "";
WordprocessingDocument? wordprocessingDocument = null;
int count = 0;
try
{
wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileStream, false);
OpenXmlValidator validator = new OpenXmlValidator(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.FileFormatVersions.Microsoft365);
foreach (ValidationErrorInfo error in validator.Validate(wordprocessingDocument))
{
count++;
if (count == 1)
errorDescription = "Description: " + error.Description;
else
errorDescription += error.Description;
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
count++;
errorDescription = ex.Message;
}
finally
{
if(wordprocessingDocument is not null)
wordprocessingDocument.Dispose();
}

I also tried with the other supported versions of the Word format, from Office2007 to Office2021, with the same error.
Can anyone help me understand?
Thanks!
The element has invalid child element http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main:rtl
I would have expected the validation to have been successful.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77816338/10024425
