OpenXml always creates corrupted .xlsx file C# (.Net NuGet package)
I'm having an issue with the DocumentFormat.OpenXml NuGet package. Although the CloseDocument() function shows that the data is getting into the excel workbook, when I try to load it up into Excel, it throws an error about the worksheet being full of errors and needing to be deleted. I've looked at multiple tutorials and other posts about issues with creating excel files, but none have helped resolve this issue.
Creating Excel File:
Excel NewExcel = new Excel(FileName);

NewExcel.CreateSheet("Test Sheet");
NewExcel.PrepareColumn(1, 80, true, 55.5);
NewExcel.CreateRow(20.2);
NewExcel.SetCell("Test 1", 1, "A");
NewExcel.SetCell(new DateTime(2010, 7, 14), 1, "B");
NewExcel.FinishSheet();
NewExcel.SaveFile();
NewExcel.CloseDocument();

Error:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><logFileName>error133640_01.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\Users\Frasher Gray\Documents\NsPaintRequest-20240702.xlsx'</summary><removedRecords><removedRecord>Removed Records: Worksheet properties from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)</removedRecord></removedRecords></recoveryLog>

Excel File Creation:
    public class Excel
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        private SpreadsheetDocument ExcelWorkbook;

        private WorksheetPart? CurrentWorksheet;

        private Columns ColumnsInProgress;

        private List<Row> RowsInProgress;

        public Excel(string FileName = "Default File Name")
        {
            this.FileName = FileName;
            ExcelWorkbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create($"C://Users/Frasher Gray/Documents/{FileName}.xlsx", SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

            ExcelWorkbook.AddWorkbookPart();
            ExcelWorkbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

            ColumnsInProgress = new Columns();
            RowsInProgress = new List<Row>();
        }

        public void PrepareColumn(int FirstColumnAffected, int LastColumnAffected, bool UseCustomWidth = false, double CustomWidth = 0)
        {
            if (UseCustomWidth)
                ColumnsInProgress.Append(new Column() { Min = new UInt32Value((uint)FirstColumnAffected), Max = new UInt32Value((uint)LastColumnAffected), CustomWidth = true, Width = new DoubleValue(CustomWidth) });
            else
                ColumnsInProgress.Append(new Column() { Min = new UInt32Value((uint)FirstColumnAffected), Max = new UInt32Value((uint)LastColumnAffected) });
        }

        public void CreateRow(double? CustomHeight = null)
        {
            SheetData SheetData = CurrentWorksheet.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>() ?? CurrentWorksheet.Worksheet.AppendChild(new SheetData());
            Row NewRow = new Row() { RowIndex = new UInt32Value((uint)SheetData.Count() + 1) };
            if (CustomHeight != null)
                NewRow.Height = CustomHeight;
            RowsInProgress.Add(NewRow);
            SheetData.Append(NewRow);
        }

        public void SetCell<T>(T CellValue, int Row, string Column)
        {
            Cell NewCell = new Cell() { CellReference = $"{Column}{Row}" };
            if (CellValue.GetType() == typeof(string))
            {
                NewCell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
                NewCell.CellValue = new CellValue(CellValue.ToString() ?? string.Empty);
            }
            else if (CellValue.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                NewCell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Date);
                NewCell.CellValue = new CellValue(Convert.ToDateTime(CellValue));
            }
            else
            {
                NewCell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);
                NewCell.CellValue = new CellValue(Convert.ToDouble(CellValue));
            }

            if (RowsInProgress[Row - 1].Elements<Cell>().Count() > 0)
            {
                RowsInProgress[Row - 1].InsertAfter(NewCell, RowsInProgress[Row - 1].Elements<Cell>().Last());
            }
            else
            {
                RowsInProgress[Row - 1].AddChild(NewCell);
            }
            CurrentWorksheet.Worksheet.Save();
        }

        public void CreateSheet(string SheetName)
        {
            CurrentWorksheet = ExcelWorkbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            CurrentWorksheet.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

            Sheets Sheets = ExcelWorkbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>() ?? ExcelWorkbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
            uint SheetId = (uint)(Sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Count() + 1);
            Sheet Sheet = new Sheet() { Id = ExcelWorkbook.GetIdOfPart(ExcelWorkbook.WorkbookPart), SheetId = SheetId, Name = SheetName };
            Sheets.Append(Sheet);
        }

        public void FinishSheet()
        {
            CurrentWorksheet.Worksheet.InsertAt(ColumnsInProgress, 0);
            ColumnsInProgress = new Columns();
            RowsInProgress.Clear();
            CurrentWorksheet.Worksheet.Save();
        }

        public void SaveFile()
        {
            ExcelWorkbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
        }

        public void CloseDocument()
        {
            foreach (Row R in ExcelWorkbook.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.FirstOrDefault().Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>())
            {
                foreach (Cell P in R.ChildElements)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(P.InnerText + " " + P.CellReference);
                }
            }
            ExcelWorkbook.Dispose();
        }
    }

Adding in validation code I borrowed from this blogpost into the CloseDocument() function, extra error information is given:

There are 1 validation errors with document
Description: The relationship 'R2c7e7002bf544f0d' referenced by attribute 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships:id' does not exist.
ErrorType: Semantic
Node: DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet
Path: /x:workbook[1]/x:sheets[1]/x:sheet[1]
Part: /xl/workbook.xml

I tried removing the ColumnsInProgress = new Columns() call after finishing the sheet, but that didn't change anything. I'm not knowledgeable enough to truly understand what the error means, unfortunately.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77816338/10024425. It's written for Word, but the same process will work for Excel. The post details how to use the Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool to generate the code for you which you can study and then modify to suit your needs.

Thank you for the help, but the code I posted above is already based off of functioning OpenXml code. I'm trying to make a class that can be used to create an excel file of any design, so I can't just make a template to feed the Productivity Tool and modify the result.

I have found the following tool is useful sometimes but not always in this scenario. It is a VS Code plugin, but it might be worth installing VS Code just to make use of it  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mikeebowen.ooxml-validator-vscode

I posted above is already based off of functioning OpenXml code...it throws an error about the worksheet being full of errors and needing to be deleted: It seems that you're in denial - your current code doesn't work correctly. If it did, you wouldn't receive those errors when opening the file in Excel. So as I stated before, create a side project, and use the Productivity Tool to assist you in generating code that works correctly. Once you have code that works correctly, you can examine it and then modify it (or generalize it).

I'm trying to make a class that can be used to create an excel file of any design: It's not clear what this means? Are you trying to create your own program similar to Excel or Libre Office? ClosedXML or NPOI?

Yeah, my code doesn't work. What I meant was that the code I based mine off of functioned, so theoretically I wouldn't get any different of a result if I used the Productivity Tool.

theoretically I wouldn't get any different of a result if I used the Productivity Tool: It's often one's own reasoning (ie: thought processes) that prevents one from finding a solution to one's issue. The saying You can lead a [thirsty] horse to water, but you can't make him drink seems to apply here.

I found a wonderful post here whose code is telling me the issue is a non-existent relationship referenced by http://schemas/openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships:id

After cutting down on as many function calls as I could to see where the reference error starting appearing, I discovered that I was assigning the Id of the sheet completely incorrectly. It should be as so:
Sheet Sheet = new Sheet() { Id = ExcelWorkbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(CurrentWorksheet), SheetId = SheetId, Name = SheetName };

