Hitting a wall attempting C# method using OpenXML SDK to export all the DataTables in a DataSet to be sheets in a new Excel Workbook
Here is a partial method to create a byte array that could be written to an xslx file that takes a DataSet and exports all the tables in that DataSet as sheets in an Excel workbook.... EXCEPT that all I have been able to do so far is get the sheets itself created, I can't for the life of me figure out how to populate those sheets with actual data:
    private byte[] DataSetToXlsx (DataSet ds)
    {
        byte[] bytes;

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheet.AddWorkbookPart();
                workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());  // This line needs to be here and I don't fully understand why

                Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

                for (int iTable = 0; iTable < ds.Tables.Count; iTable++)
                {
                    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[iTable];

                    var sheet = new Sheet
                    {
                        Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
                        SheetId = (uint)iTable + 1,
                        Name = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dt.TableName) ? $"Sheet {iTable + 1}" : dt.TableName
                    };

                    // Now I want to iterate through the DataRows on the table to transfer the values into the sheet, but I just can't figure out how to do it.

                    sheets.Append(sheet);
                }

                workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            }
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            bytes = stream.ToArray();
        }

        return bytes;
    }

I realize that partly I don't fully grasp the difference between a Worksheet and a Sheet.  And as my comments in the code would suggest, I don't fully understand WNY I need to create a single new Worksheet but one Sheet for every DataTable in the DataSet.
But my code does work to create a new workbook, and to put in that workbook a sheet for every DataTable.
But more to the point, I do not understand how to start creating rows in the Sheet instances so that the actual data itself gets reflected.  I am just baffled at how to do this.  Every attempt I have made compiles just fine but creates corrupted files that Excel can't read.
I would love to know the trick!
Please do not point me to third party libraries, or to Excel interrop.

Create the desired Excel workbook using Excel, then use the Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool to generate the C# code. The following post describes the process in more detail. It was written for Word, but the same process applies to Excel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77816338/10024425 .

Thanks for the idea.... may give it a try.

I figured out the answer - here is my modified code:
    private byte[] DataSetToXlsx (DataSet ds)
    {
        if (ds == null || ds.Tables.Count < 1)
        {
            return null;
        }

        byte[] bytes;

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                // Setup requirements for minimal spreadsheet document - workbook and sheets.
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheet.AddWorkbookPart();
                workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
                Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

                for (int iTable = 0; iTable < ds.Tables.Count; iTable++)
                {
                    // Add a new worksheet part for the table
                    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                    worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

                    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[iTable];

                    // Add sheet to the workbook with ID from worksheet
                    sheets.Append(new Sheet
                    {
                        Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
                        SheetId = (uint)iTable + 1,
                        Name = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dt.TableName) ? $"Sheet {iTable + 1}" : dt.TableName
                    });

                    if (dt.Columns.Count < 1)
                    {
                        continue;  // No data in this table.
                    }

                    // Get the sheetData for the grid on which we will place rows.
                    SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

                    CellValues[] columnTypes = new CellValues[dt.Columns.Count];

                    // Retrieve header data from the table columns and place in first row of the sheet
                    var row = new Row { RowIndex = 1 };
                    for (int iColumn = 0; iColumn < dt.Columns.Count; iColumn++)
                    {
                        DataColumn dc = dt.Columns[iColumn];

                        columnTypes[iColumn] = FindCellValuesForColumn(dc);

                        row.Append(new Cell { DataType = CellValues.String, CellValue = new CellValue(dc.ColumnName) });
                    }
                    sheetData?.Append(row);

                    // Retrieve remaining data from table rows and populate the sheet
                    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < dt.Rows.Count; iRow++)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[iRow];
                        row = new Row { RowIndex = (uint)iRow + 2 };
                        for(int iColumn = 0; iColumn < dt.Columns.Count; iColumn++)
                        {
                            row.Append(new Cell { DataType = columnTypes[iColumn], CellValue = CellValueFromObject(dr[iColumn]) });
                        }
                        sheetData?.Append(row);
                    }
                }

                workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            }
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            bytes = stream.ToArray();
        }

        return bytes;
    }

This does depend on a couple of helper methods and a static lookup table which I have also included here:
    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, Tuple<CellValues, Func<object, CellValue>>> TypeLookup = new ReadOnlyDictionary<Type, Tuple<CellValues, Func<object, CellValue>>>(new Dictionary<Type, Tuple<CellValues, Func<object, CellValue>>>
    {
        { typeof(char), new Tuple<CellValues, Func<object, CellValue>>(CellValues.String, o => new CellValue(o.ToString())) },
        { typeof(string), new Tuple<CellValues, Func<object, CellValue>>(CellValues.String, o => new CellValue((string)o)) },
        { typeof(DateTime), new Tuple<CellValues, Func<object, CellValue>>(CellValues.Date, o => new CellValue((DateTime)o)) },
        { typeof(bool), new Tuple<CellValues, Func<object, CellValue>>(CellValues.Boolean, o => new CellValue((bool)o)) },
        { typeof(byte), new Tuple<CellValues, Func<object, CellValue>>(CellValues.Number, o => new CellValue(Convert.ToInt32(o))) },
        { typeof(short), new Tuple<CellValues, Func<object, CellValue>>(CellValues.Number, o => new CellValue(Convert.ToInt32(o))) },
        { typeof(int), new Tuple<CellValues, Func<object, CellValue>>(CellValues.Number, o => new CellValue((int)o)) },
        { typeof(long), new Tuple<CellValues, Func<object, CellValue>>(CellValues.Number, o => new CellValue(o.ToString())) },
        { typeof(ushort), new Tuple<CellValues, Func<object, CellValue>>(CellValues.Number, o => new CellValue(o.ToString())) },
        { typeof(uint), new Tuple<CellValues, Func<object, CellValue>>(CellValues.Number, o => new CellValue(o.ToString())) },
        { typeof(ulong), new Tuple<CellValues, Func<object, CellValue>>(CellValues.Number, o => new CellValue(o.ToString())) },
        { typeof(float), new Tuple<CellValues, Func<object, CellValue>>(CellValues.Number, o => new CellValue(Convert.ToDouble(o))) },
        { typeof(double), new Tuple<CellValues, Func<object, CellValue>>(CellValues.Number, o => new CellValue((double)o)) },
        { typeof(decimal), new Tuple<CellValues, Func<object, CellValue>>(CellValues.Number, o => new CellValue((decimal)o)) }
    });

    private static CellValue CellValueFromObject (object obj)
    {
        return obj == null
            ? new CellValue()
            : TypeLookup.TryGetValue(obj.GetType(), out Tuple<CellValues, Func<object, CellValue>> tuple)
                ? tuple.Item2(obj)
                : new CellValue(Convert.ToString(obj));
    }

    private static CellValues FindCellValuesForColumn(DataColumn dc)
    {
        dc = dc ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dc));

        if (TypeLookup.TryGetValue(dc.DataType, out Tuple<CellValues, Func<object, CellValue>> tuple))
        {
            return tuple.Item1;
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException($"No CellValues mapping available for data type \"{dc.DataType.FullName}\" for column \"{dc.ColumnName}\" in table \"{dc.Table?.TableName}\" in dataset \"{dc.Table?.DataSet?.DataSetName}\"");
    }

